# JSF Page Navigation: If A.jsf navigate to B.jsf via hyperlink, why the URL display A.jsf instead of B.jsf

Tags: jsf, faces-config

If `A.jsf` have a `commandLink` that will navigation to `B.jsf`, then I would think when I am at page `B.jsf`, I see `http:domain/host/project/B.jsf` as the URL. However, I see `http:domain/host/project/A.jsf` on my address bar. **I am always ONE behind when displaying the URL in navigation control**. Is there away to fix this? My navigation control is handle inside `faces-config.xml`.

Try this like `Plaudit Design - Web Design` suggest. However does not fix it.

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/CentralFeed.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>CREATE EVENT</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/CreateEvent.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>CREATE ARTICLE</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/WriteArticle.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>PROFILE</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/Profile.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <redirect/>
</navigation-rule>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the following inside your navigation-rule

```
<redirect/>
```

With out the redirect element the redirect is internal. The redirect causes an external redirect so your browser requests the new page.

Comment: It does not work for me. I edit my post with some codes, can u take a look at it?

Comment: It should go inside the navigation case. Note that any request scoped beans will be recreated. Also, if no business action is involved, I'd suggest to just use `h:outputLink`. That's also more SEO friendly. Or if you're already on JSF 2.0, use `h:link` instead.

Comment: Can u explain to me what is it mean by internal redirect and external redirect?

Comment: By "internal redirect" I mean the server decides internally to display the page B.jsf even though the page requested by the browser was A.jsf. The browsers location bar shows what was requested. Adding the <redirect/> instructs JSF to respond with a "Location:" header which tells the browser to make new request for B.jsf.